# Is there a "File IO in Postscript for Dummies"?

Tags: file, io, postscript

Much of the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) played on Stack Overflow involved ASCII figures, and [codegolf.SE](http://codegold.stackexchange.com) is shaping up the same way.

That's all well and good, but I'd like to inject a little variety into the output, and have written my recent question [Output a playable crossword grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1197/78) explicitly to encourage graphical format entries.

To show willing, I've started trying to hack together a reference implementation in postscript. Alas, I'm completely new to the language, and am having trouble doing basic file IO. Does anyone know of a basic resource that covers the topic?

I am aware of

- `file`
- `(%stdin)`
- `token`
- `readstring`
- `readline`

but I am pretty unclear on exactly what the last three return and how one manipulates it after you've got it.

I *have* figured out that several return a `<value> <boolean>` pair, and that I can use `if` to test the boolean. Then what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good book about postscript is "thinking in postscript" by Gleen Reid. You used to be able to get the book free for personal use from his website, but its down. You can still download it from
http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090621100720/http://www.rightbrain.com/pages/books.html

Chapter 14 covers file io and has sample code.

Comment: I'd make it +2 if I could for taking the time to find a waybackmachine link. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I've only been at this postscript for 2 days now, but I'm thinking anyone "thinking in postscript" would have to be... insane?  Great reference though.

Comment: No longer available on Wayback, fails to download. But a direct Google search for "ThinkingInPostScript.pdf" can find it in Jan 2023.

Answer (score 6):

There are some tricks and shortcuts to File IO in postscript that often aren't mentioned in the introductory sections of postscript books. The best-kept secret among them is the 'token' operator. It allows you to borrow the interpreter's own scanner to read a bareword (producing a nametype object), a number (producing 
an integertype or realtype object), or an array of these (but only if you use the executable-array notation, ie. curly braces, otherwise you just get a marktype object which represents the left square bracket).

As a simple example, I often use this one-liner to embed an extended commentary section in a postscript program:

```
%!
{ currentfile token pop /END-COMMENT eq {exit} if } loop
Each word here is read from the current file and converted
into a name object and compared to "/END-COMMENT".
It can have but does not need a preceeding slash.

This program produces an image of a snowman in a blizzard,
suitable for use as stationary.
END-COMMENT

showpage
```

**Edit:** I realize now that this is a really terrible answer ... so far.

My example above is little more than:

```
(Some
multi-line
text)
pop
```

So, for real this time.

To start with, you need a `loop`.

```
{
} loop
```

An inside this loop, you read some data.

```
/src (datafile) (r) file def
{
    src readline
} loop
```

As you observed, the file-reading operators all return a boolean on the top of the stack. Perfect!

```
/src (datafile) (r) file def
{
    src readline {
    }{
        exit
    } ifelse
} loop
```

So a boolean true will do something and keep looping, but a boolean false (no-more-data) causes the loop to terminate. But `readline` needs a string to put its data into. And it returns the string even in the false case.

```
/src (datafile) (r) file def
/str 80 string def
{
    src str readline {
        processline
    }{
        pop exit
    } ifelse
} loop
```

Now we have a string containing a line (80 chars max) of data from the file. If it resembles Postscript syntax at all, you can use `token` in a loop (like my first example; it reads each word from the file, converts it to an Executable Name and then compares it to a Literal Name; if the names match, exit the loop). Or you can use `get` in a loop (or the `forall` loop) to extract each byte as an integer. But the cool thing to do is `search`.

This procedure scans a string for space-delimited words and prints each one to stdout on its own line.

```
/processline { % (line)
     ( ) { % (line) ( )
         search { % (post) ( ) (pre)
             =
         }{ % (no-match)
             =
             exit
         } ifelse
     } loop
} def
```

It's usually easier just to duplicate cases here, when you want to do the same thing to the last word as all the others. You *can* do some tricky stuff to process the topmost string and *then* test the boolean; but it's not really worth the hassle. The cool thing about `search` is the convenient order in which it returns its results. It puts the beginning of the string on top so you can work with it. Then it gives you the "match" (which is the same as the "seek" you gave initially (although it's referenced to the working string now)) and the remainder; and they're already in the correct order for the next go 'round the loop.

So what do you want to do with your extracted, space-delimited words read from an external file?

If they represent numbers, you can `cvi` or `cvr` them and do arithmetic. If they're alphanumeric, you can `print` or `show` them; or `cvn` them and use them as atomic symbols.

Comment: I posted a [wrapper function for readline](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.postscript/browse_thread/thread/6799414eb7490e52#) that will grow the string buffer to hold lines of indefinite length.

Comment: I've got an example of "tricky stuff to process the topmost string and *then* test the Boolean" [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/h4CtQ-7edu0/7plTa2cP0I8J).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to convert a simple text file (representing a crossword puzzle layout) to PostScript code that draws that crossword puzzle on a page. While it is true that PostScript is Turing-complete, and thus can be programmed to do this, I think programming the whole thing in PostScript is not a good approach.

PostScript is a tricky language to program in, especially if you want to mess around with arbitrary data. When I want PostScript output, I start by hacking together some sample PostScript that draws what I want, with all the parameters hardcoded. Then I write code in some other language that outputs that PostScript code, varying the appropriate parts as needed based on the input.

I see that doesn't read very well, so here's an example. If I have an input file that contains the radius of a circle, then I'll write a program in Python that reads that radius, then writes PostScript code to draw the circle, with the radius hardcoded in the PostScript.

I started working on a crossword puzzle project years ago. Didn't get too far, but the attached PostScript code will draw a small crossword puzzle. Note that "proper" PostScript follows some document conventions that I didn't bother with; I have some sketchy notes about them that I can post.

This PostScript code does do some calculations. Generally I'll write functions in PostScript for things I expect to do a lot, or for things that need data that only the PostScript interpreter will have, e.g., the width of a string in the current font, for centering.

I haven't cleaned this up any. Feel free to ask for clarifications. HTH.

```
%!

% "Example"
% by (author)
% Generated 16 Apr 2005 22:19 by (program name)

% should really be eps

% unit conversions

/inch {72 mul} bind def
/cm {inch 2.54 div} bind def



%%%%%% start of adjustable parameters

% these may be fiddled with, within reason
% be careful not to change the syntax

% paper size
/page_width 8.5 inch def
/page_height 11 inch def

% page margins
/top_margin 1 inch def
/left_margin 1 inch def

% how many "cells" wide and high
/puzzle_width 9 def
/puzzle_height 9 def

% cell_size: height and width of a one-letter square, in points
/cell_size .25 inch def

% line width, in points. 1 is about maximum.
/line_width .375 def

% font and size for the numbers
/cell_font {/Helvetica 5} bind def

% top/left margin for numbers within a cell
/num_margin 1.5 def

%%%%%% end of adjustable parameters



<< /PageSize [page_width page_height] >> setpagedevice


/w_pts puzzle_width cell_size mul def
/h_pts puzzle_height cell_size mul def

/ulx left_margin def
/uly page_height top_margin sub def
/lrx ulx w_pts add def
/lry uly h_pts sub def


% draw grid

line_width setlinewidth
0 setgray

newpath ulx uly w_pts h_pts neg rectstroke

lry cell_size uly {
  newpath ulx exch moveto w_pts 0 rlineto stroke
} for

ulx cell_size lrx {
  newpath lry moveto 0 h_pts rlineto stroke
} for


% fill in black spaces

% ulx uly width height blackrect
% all in terms of cells; upper-left-most is 0,0
/blackrect
{
  << >> begin
  /h exch def /w exch def /y exch def /x exch def
  newpath
  ulx x cell_size mul add
  uly y cell_size mul sub
  w cell_size mul
  h cell_size mul neg
  rectfill
  end
} bind def

0 setgray
0 0 1 1 blackrect
3 0 2 1 blackrect
8 0 1 1 blackrect
4 1 1 1 blackrect
2 2 1 1 blackrect
6 2 1 1 blackrect
8 3 1 1 blackrect
0 4 2 1 blackrect
7 4 2 1 blackrect
0 5 1 1 blackrect
2 6 1 1 blackrect
6 6 1 1 blackrect
4 7 1 1 blackrect
0 8 1 1 blackrect
4 8 2 1 blackrect
8 8 1 1 blackrect


% draw numbers

% x y h s drawnum
% x and y in terms of cells; upper-left-most is 0,0. s is string.
% h is height of numbers. should never change, so compute once before any calls.
/drawnum
{
  << >> begin
  /s exch def /h exch def /y exch def /x exch def
  newpath
  ulx x cell_size mul add num_margin add
  uly y cell_size mul sub num_margin sub h sub
  moveto s show
  end
} bind def

0 setgray
cell_font selectfont

% compute font height
mark
newpath 0 0 moveto
(0) false charpath flattenpath pathbbox
/fh exch def
cleartomark newpath

1 0 fh (1) drawnum
2 0 fh (2) drawnum
5 0 fh (3) drawnum
6 0 fh (4) drawnum
7 0 fh (5) drawnum
0 1 fh (6) drawnum
3 1 fh (7) drawnum
5 1 fh (8) drawnum
8 1 fh (9) drawnum
0 2 fh (10) drawnum
3 2 fh (11) drawnum
4 2 fh (12) drawnum
7 2 fh (13) drawnum
0 3 fh (14) drawnum
2 3 fh (15) drawnum
6 3 fh (16) drawnum
2 4 fh (17) drawnum
1 5 fh (18) drawnum
7 5 fh (19) drawnum
8 5 fh (20) drawnum
0 6 fh (21) drawnum
3 6 fh (22) drawnum
7 6 fh (23) drawnum
0 7 fh (24) drawnum
2 7 fh (25) drawnum
5 7 fh (26) drawnum
6 7 fh (27) drawnum
1 8 fh (28) drawnum
6 8 fh (29) drawnum


showpage
```

Comment: So writing in c to produce postscript was an alternative approach, but I thought it would be cute to simply do it in postscript. I take it that's tough. I've laid hands on the reference manual and the blue and green books, so I should be OK with everything other than the IO which keeps throwing an unimplemented trap in my brain. *::sigh::*

Comment: Well, it's tough for me. A real PS hacker might find it easy. I only have the ref manual.

I would use Python myself; I see you've used it, but perhaps not very much. It's so much more productive, my C skills are rusty now.